# Using Jython to extract business data from the WebSphere Failed Event Manager

Tags: jython

I normally work with shellscript, but I'm dabbling in Jython for my current client. I need to extract and display business data from a failed event in WebSphere, and I can't figure out how to do it.

The code I have so far is

```
green='\033[0;32m'
cyan='\033[0;36m'
clear='\033[0m'
##########################################################################
import time
today=time.asctime().split(' ')
objstr = AdminControl.completeObjectName('WebSphere:*,type=FailedEventManager')
obj = AdminControl.makeObjectName(objstr)
fecount = AdminControl.invoke(objstr,"getFailedEventCount")
msglist = AdminControl.invoke_jmx(obj,'getAllFailedEvents',[0],['int'])
i=0
for fe in msglist:
   i+=1
   ftd=str(fe.getFailureDateTime()).split(' ')
   if ftd[1]==today[1] and ftd[2]==today[2] and ftd[5]==today[4]:
      col=green
   else:
      col=cyan
   fstr="%4d: %-46s "+col+"%s"+clear
   print fstr % (i, fe.getMsgId(), fe.getFailureDateTime() )
```

Which displays the message ID and the timestamp of the event. But I've looked around the net, and can't figure out how to get from what I've got to actually extracting specific parameters from the business data for each failed event.

I'd appreciate if somebody with greater knowledge of Jython than I have could point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Douglas

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you got your answer.
Posting what I know to help who is looking for: 
You can use getFailedEventParameters to get business data of failed events.

```
  scaDetail = AdminControl.invoke_jmx(obj,'getEventDetailForSCA',[event], ['com.ibm.wbiserver.manualrecovery.FailedEvent'])
   eventDetailParameter = scaDetail.getFailedEventParameters()
   for failedParameter in eventDetailParameter:
           print failedParameter.getName()
           print failedParameter.getType()
           print failedParameter.getValue()
```